# I can't get rid of index.php in my urls on Codeigniter with XAMPP/Apache 2.4.9/PHP 5.5.11, and I've tried 4 solutions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Mod_Rewrite is on. I've created an .htaccess file inside the htdocs/ci_intro folder that contains: application, system, and index.php files

My .htaccess file content:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I've changed the application/config/config.php to:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I also changed httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
#   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

this URL works

```
http://localhost/ci_intro/index.php/site/about
```

this URL brings "Object Not Found" 404

```
http://localhost/ci_intro/site/about
```

I've tried 4 different .htaccess file versions, from different blog answers.
I'm on Windows 8.1 OS. I'm new, done some javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: Didn't know what, if anything to put after RewriteBase / , where Codeigniter.php is?

Comment: Since you put the codeigniter inside ci_intro, your base should be /ci_intro/

Comment: I found it, I just had to have the right code in the .htaccess, and it works, what a pain in the butt.